# How to make a layout where 3 items are centered in height/width of the HTML page

Tags: html, css

Well the basic layout I want is:
[image: Layout]

Keep in mind those items on the side should be centered in the part between the center one and the side of the page.

I'm looking for a valid cross-browser(HTML5/CSS3 compatible is fine) solution for an HTML page which hopefully doesn't use javascript

Comment: Are the elements you want to place of fixed height?

Comment: yes, but I found out how to do it, I should have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="top:50%" align="center">
<div> STUFF 1 </div>
<div> STUFF 2 </div>
<div> STUFF 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To get it exactly in the middle put a negative top margin on the containing `div` of half the height of the boxes.